# There is a shorter way to solve multiple links with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I am new to jQuery and programing in general. I finished my first web site and decided to use jQuery to solve most of the code, not because it was better but because I needed to practice.

Now, the site has a list of links and I use a code like the one below repeated 12 times:

```
$('#id_of_the_div').on('click', function () {
    window.open("http://example.com/", '_blank');
});
```

Now it sounds to me that maybe there is a better way than this, because I only have 12 links in my website but, what if I have 30 or 50 links? Take in account that the site is only HTML and jQuery, no PHP or server side code for now.

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sergeen/RB3aZ/

Thanks!

Comment: use the `a` (anchor) elements instead of jquery, I've updated your fiddle where `a` tags are used: http://jsfiddle.net/RB3aZ/1/

Comment: Just in case there's a very good reason for you to use `div` instead of `a` and you just want to reduce the amount of jquery code, you can do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RB3aZ/3/

Comment: @patrick-q This is what I was looking for. I know that an `<a>` element is the correct way to do it. But I wanted to practice some jQuery and ask for a better way that I can use in other scenarios :) Thk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using divs because it's easier to style them, but you can still do the same when using `<a>` tag with `display:block;`

[Like THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RB3aZ/6/)

Or, if you prefer what you have now, using below:

```
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
        window.open($(this).data('link'), '_blank');
    })
;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RB3aZ/4/)

Personally option one is a better solution.

Comment: I like this answer short and sweet (y)

Comment: The second one is the one that I was looking for! Thanks! I know that HTML markup is a better solution but I wanted to explore a shorter jQuery method for the same thing, even if in the end I finish adding the same amount of code in the HTML markup. Thanks for both answers!

Comment: @Sergio you are quite welcome. It is fun to do things in many different ways. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You got the concept of divisions wrong.
If you want to add links use the  Anchor Tag.

```
<html>
<a href="http://example.com/">Example</a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the HTML element that was created for this task, our good old friend `<a>` ;)

```
<a href="http://myurl.com">My text</a>
```

By default, it looks like a blue link, which I think is what you are trying to avoid. But it's much easier to change the style of the link, rather than try using other elements that usually do not redirect to other pages.

Add this to a CSS file, or to a `<style>` tag on your page:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;  /* no underline */
    color: black;           /* changes the color of the text*/
    background-color: red;  /* changes the background color*/
    padding: 10px;          /*this makes sure you have some open space so your item looks like a button */
  }
```

Note that this CSS snippet changes the style of ALL `<a>` elements on the page. It looks like a button, but if you click it, it still works like a link.

**Update**

If you also want to remove the underline when you hover over the link, also add the following to the CSS:

```
a:hover {   /* :hover is the state of the item when the mouse is over it, but you're not clicking (yet) */
    text-decoration: none;  /* no underline */
  }
```

Comment: Or you could wrap the <a/> with the div and have the same class like this http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/RB3aZ/2/

Comment: Also correct. But why use two items when one suffices? :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using something like this

```
$('#js').on('click', function () {
    window.open("http://jsfiddle.net/", '_blank');
});
```

you can remove js part and replace in html

```
<a class="link" href="http://jsfiddle.net/" target="_blank" id="js">JSFIDDLE</a>
```

and then change css to style anchor elements of class link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement with your current markup -

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'js':
            window.open("http://jsfiddle.net/", '_blank');
            break;
        case 'careers':
            window.open("http://careers.stackoverflow.com/", '_blank');
            break;
    }
});
```

Or you could change your markup to help you be more efficient by adding the URL information -

```
<div class="link" id="js" data-url="http://jsfiddle.net">JSFIDDLE</div>
<div class="link" id="careers" data-url="http://careers.stackoverflow.com">CAREERS @ STACKOVERFLOW</div>
```

And then your code block gets much shorter -

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
    var thisURL = $(this).data('url');
    window.open(thisURL, '_blank');
});
```

But you should switch to anchor tags for your links. You can still use the kind of coding that I have provided here.

Answer (score 0):

create function for this

```
function goNewLink(id,url){
    $("#"+id).on('click', function () {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
}
```

use  goNewLink("id","www.example.com");

Comment: This ends up as a longer piece of code, since you're replacing a single-line redirect with a call to a function that does the redirect for you. Basically, the code has grown by the amount of lines that additional function takes up; without anything changing functionally :)

Comment: function you should write in one place and then call from other places

Comment: Not questioning the principle of creating reusable code. But write it out and see for yourself, the amount of code has increased, not decreased. Because your new function call (single-line), takes up as much space as the code you're trying to replace (also a single-line). So it doesn't become any shorter. Since OP is using hard-coded strings, reusable code doesn't seem to be an important factor (no offense meant to anyone). If it is important, there are other optimalizations that could be done to actually both decrease the amount of code, and make it more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use `div` tags because of their shape, there's an easier way to do that. Use anchor tags and apply `display: block` (anchor tags are normally `display: inline` by default, where styles like `width` don't apply):

```
.link {
    display: block; /* make them "rectangular" elements */
    text-decoration: none; /* remove underlines -- optional */
    /* the rest is the same */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="link" id="js" href="http://jsfiddle.net/" target="_blank">JSFIDDLE</a>
    <a class="link" id="careers" href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">CAREERS @ STACKOVERFLOW</a>
    <a class="link" id="meta" href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">META @ STACKOVERFLOW</a>
    <a class="link" id="stack" href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">STACKOVERFLOW @ STACKOVERFLOW</a>
    <a class="link" id="alist" href="http://alistapart.com/" target="_blank">A LIST APART</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/j5UP5/